# Using SetupDiGetClassDevs

Tags: .net, usb

Is "SetupDiGetClassDevs"  in the .NET framwork, if so which "using System"? namespace is it in.  Or do I need to load "Setupapi.lib" or "Setupapi.dll" first.  If so, loading the dll, is there an example of that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DllImport.  You can import it to a VB.net application using the following declaration:

```
<DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Public Shared Function SetupDiGetClassDevs( _
ByRef ClassGuid As Guid, _
ByVal Enumerator As IntPtr, _
ByVal hwndParent As IntPtr, _
ByVal Flags As Integer) As IntPtr

End Function
```

You'll need to do some Googling to see how it works.